# Can anyone help me what is wrong with my python script?

Tags: python, syntax

I wrote a python script and got an 'invalid syntax' error. Can anyone help me to find the error? Thanks.

Piece of my code:

```
class Mahjong():
    mentsu_map = {}
    def __init__(self):
        if len(Mahjong.mentsu_map) == 0:
            m = Mahjong.mentsu_map
            m[0] = [0, 0]
            tablefile = open("pretable.data", "r")
            try:
                for line in tablefile:
                    ls = map(int, line.split(' '))
                    m[ls[0]] = [ m[ls[1], m[ls[2]] ]
            finally: # invalid syntax here
                tablefile.close()

    def shanten(self, ht): 
        pass
```

And my error output is:

```
    finally:
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: iCodez was right; you're missing a ] bracket in the line before "finally"

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is too localized.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgot a `]`

```
m[ls[0]] = [ m[ls[1]], m[ls[2]] ]
```

instead of

```
m[ls[0]] = [ m[ls[1], m[ls[2]] ]
```

Comment: Also suggest `with` statement, it was introduced to get rid of these `try-finally`.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing one closing square brackets here :)

Added:

```
m[ls[0]] = [ m[ls[1]], m[ls[2]] ]
```

If you're on +Python 2.6, to optimize you can also use the `with` statement:

```
with open("pretable.data", "r") as tablefile:
    for line in tablefile:
            ls = map(int, line.split(' '))
            m[ls[0]] = [ m[ls[1]], m[ls[2]] ]
```

Which will automatically close the file after the code block is successfully executed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks. I find to use 'with' is clearer.